# Do either or with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I do the following:

```
var section = $('#order_items_section') || $("#assets_section");
```

Basically, I want to get the second one only if the first doesn't exist. However, this gives me `null` if the first is empty and the second exists.

What would be the correct syntax here?

Comment: `$("#order_items_section,#assets_section").eq(0);` If they're listed in document order. If they're reversed, use `.last()` instead of `.eq(0)`

Comment: That will never give you `null`. Always a jQuery object.

Comment: If a selector doesn't match any elements, the result is a jquery object with no elements in it, not null. `if ($('selector'))` is always true/non-null.

Answer (score 10):

Ternary operators are best for this

```
var section = $('#order_items_section').length ? $('#order_items_section') : $('#assets_section');
```